# An equivalent condition for complex representations to be realize over $\mathbb{R}$ and conjugate.

Tags: representation-theory

I wonder whether there is an equivalent condition for (may not be irreducible) complex representations of a finite group to be realize over $\mathbb{R}$.

I consider the complex conjugates of representations to find an equivalent condition. The conjugate $\overline{\rho}:G\to \mathrm{GL}_{n}(\mathbb{C})$ of a representation $\rho:G\to \mathrm{GL}_{n}(\mathbb{C})$ is defined by $\overline{\rho}(g)=\overline{\rho(g)}$.

I guess that $\rho$ realize over $\mathbb{R}$(i.e., $\rho$ is isomorphic a representation over $\mathbb{R}$) if and only if $\rho$ and $\overline{\rho}$ are isomorphic. I can prove the forward direction but not the converse.

I wonder whether my guess is right or there is an other equivalent condition.

Comment: There must be another condition: the two-dimensional complex representation of the quaternion group $Q_8$ is not realisable over $\mathbb{R}$. You might want to search for "Frobenius-Schur indicator".

Comment: Thank you, Joppy. You are right $Q_{8}$ is a counter example for my guess.